# Sql code for displaying one account from two relational tables

Tags: php

I want to display only one account from the two relational table. For example if I inquire my account number and enter it, only the details of my account will be shown not every members. So in my output the whole members and its details inside the database display. How can I manage to display only one account from two relational tables? I know there is something wrong in my sql.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT member.*, account.*
FROM member, account
WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id';

mysql_select_db('databasename');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ); 
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Account Number:{$row['Account_Number']}  <br> ".
 "First Name: {$row['fname']} <br> ".
 "Last Name: {$row['lname']} <br> ".
 "Address: {$row['address']} <br> ".
 "Contact: {$row['contact']} <br> ".
 "Share Capital: {$row['Share_Capital']} <br> ".
 "Regular Savings: {$row['Regular_Savings']} <br> ".
 "Power Savings: {$row['Power_Savings']} <br> ".
 "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Now this is the output.

```
Account Number: 
First Name:
Last Name:
Address: 
Contact: 
Share Capital: 
Regular Savings:
Power Savings:
```

Comment: Are member.mem_id = account.mem_id 1:1 ?

Comment: yes, member.mem_id = account.mem_id

Comment: Did you still need a hand with this?  If so, can you please add some sample rows from your two tables and what you _want_ the output to be?  You've got blank output, and it seems that user1533577's answer below is close.  Might point to a data issue. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I stiil need a help.I just displayed a blank output for security of the data but I want to displayed only the account that I inquiry on. When a member Login he/she enter her/his Account Number and Password. When he/she enter automatically her/his Account details will shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you haven't chosen anyone's answer as correct, I suspect you may have a data issue at hand.  But assuming that your records are truly 1 to 1, then this would do it for sure:

**Notice I added $find_id at the top as a param**

```
<?php


    $dbhost     = 'localhost';
    $dbuser     = 'root';
    $dbpass     = 'password';
    $find_id    = 12;

    try
    {

        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);   
        if( !$conn )
            throw new Exception( "Couldn't establish a connection" );

        if( !mysql_select_db('databasename', $conn )  )
            throw new Exception( "Database couldn't be selected" );

        $sql = 'SELECT M.*, A.* FROM member M LEFT JOIN account A ON M.mem_id = A.mem_id
                WHERE M.mem_id = $find_id';

        if( !($retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn )) )
            throw new Exception( "No matching result, or query was borked; " . mysql_error() );

        if( !($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $retval )) )
            throw new Exception( "No rows found, move along." );

        print_r( $row );
    }
    catch( Exception $x )
    {
        echo "An exception occurred: " . $x->getMessage();
    }
```

So that's the ugly of it all, but a few things to note:

Probably don't want to be using mysql_* functions; use PDO instead (which isn't on its way out the door) - and, use prepared params to mitigate SQL injection attacks. The super nerdy tidbit I can add is that it is usually good logic to separate authentication table routines from user-table routines since user tables, usually end up being used "outside" of this. Query for auth to establish ID, then, use the user table in a separate thread.  That way, your auth queries aren't tying up both tables.

Good luck!
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, now can I ask how can I put codes on my login page so that when I inquire it will be shown to my members page?

Answer (score 0):

To return only 1 account try

`'SELECT member.*, account.* 
        FROM member inner join account 
        on member.mem_id = account.mem_id limit 1';`

However to retrieve the member and accounts for a memberid, the query will need to change to include a where predicate on mem_id. for example:

```
    $member_id = 'some memberid'
    'SELECT member.*, account.*
    FROM member inner join account
    on member.mem_id = account.mem_id 
    where member.mem_id = $member_id';
```

Comment: 'SELECT member.*, account.* FROM member inner join account on member.mem_id = account.mem_id limit 1'; help but it only displayed the first account in the database.

Comment: ok, then I suggest you go with the second approach. You need to figure out the mem_id... or use the fname and lname. for example

    SELECT member.*, account.*
    FROM member inner join account
    on member.mem_id = account.mem_id 
    where member.fname = 'Bob' and member.lname = 'Smith'

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the same ID: "WHERE member.mem_id = account.mem_id" (I'm assuming that member.mem_id and account.mem_id reference the same "user").

You should do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT member.*, account.*
FROM member, account
WHERE member.mem_id = " . $the_id;
```

Where $the_id should be a number that you get from a form (an HTML form, to clarify).

Hope it helps :)